# Append to a.href id from input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, hyperlink

I am trying to append to a link with id a value that is entered from the input text field. I came this far searching stackoverflow but id doesn't work!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(function(){
   $("#txt_name").keypress(function() {
     var value = $("#txt_name").val();
     });
   $("a#coupon_link").attr("href", function(i) {
      return href + '&discount_code='.text(value); 
      });
});
</script>
```

and this is how the html looks like

```
<form>
  <fieldset>
    <input id="txt_name" type="text" value="discount" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
<a id="coupon_link" href="https://www.e-junkie.com/ecom/gb.php?c=cart&i=XXXXXX&cl=YYYYYY&ejc=2" target="ej_ejc" class="ec_ejc_thkbx" onClick="javascript:return EJEJC_lc(this);"><img src="http://www.e-junkie.com/ej/ej_add_to_cart.gif" border="0" alt="Add to Cart"/></a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix your code like this :

```
$(function(){
   $("#txt_name").keypress(function() {
     var value = $("#txt_name").val();
     var link = $("#coupon_link");
     var originalHref = link.attr('originalHref');
     if (!originalHref) {
          originalHref = link.attr("href");
          link.attr("originalHref", originalHref)
     }
     link.attr("href", originalHref + '&discount_code='+value);
   });
});
```

A few things to note :

- never add anything to a selector when you're targeting an element by ID
- your value variable wasn't in the same scope
- the return of `val` can be directly concatenated, you don't need to try to change it to text
- you don't need to pass a function to attr in your case
- you're trying to make the href grow with every key stroke. This is a bad idea. The solution I propose is to keep the original href
- if you're not sure the original href has yet some parameters (i.e. has '?') you should test it (I let you do that)

Overall a much cleaner solution wouldn't be to change the link but to build the href on click on the link :

```
$("#coupon_link").click(function(e) {
   location = this.href + '&discount_code=' + $('#txt_name').val();
});
```

Comment: Bad idea. I have also started to write but decided to drop. Agree, that `change` event is better here by all means (you can't click a link with not loosing a focus from input). But even with it, you can't control appending of `&discount_code=`... parsing needed... questions, questions, questions...

Comment: @VisioN I enriched my answer to avoid making the href grow at each key. If the original href is correct (and has yet a parameter), this should be OK, don't you think ?

Comment: @VisioN This is cleaner but not really different. In fact I think the whole effort misses the real need, hence the second much simpler solution I gave.

Comment: I enjoy your alternative solution -- the best approach here.

Comment: Thank you @dystroy worked as described! Thank you for the clear explanation!

Comment: @vision guess you didn't look hard enough then, because it's very similar to my answer (which also makes sure to preventDefault(). Still +1 for offering more tips :)

Comment: @Jack. I hadn't see your answer (too many ones here). Note that preventDefault isn't needed in this case as the location change is immediate and stops the script. Have a +1 anyway.

Comment: @Jack My bad, I didn't see your answer. Good promoting is always good ;)

Answer (score 3):

You probably meant this:

```
$(function() {
   $("#coupon_link").on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault(); // apparently not needed
      location.href = $(this).attr('href') + '&discount_code=' + encodeURIComponent($('#txt_name').val());
   });
});
```

You don't have to update the value of `#txt_name` on keypress; you only have to use the value when the link is pressed.

Comment: Thnx Jack i tested this much easier

Answer (score 1):

Not sure to understand, but it looks like a scope issue try this javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(function(){
   var value = 0;
   $("#txt_name").keypress(function() {
       value = $("#txt_name").val();
       $("a#coupon_link").attr("href", function(i) {
          return href + '&discount_code=' + encodeURIComponent(value); 
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to change the href when a key has been pressed, not only on page load. To do so you will have to do the replacing of the href inside the keyup function, like so:

```
$(function(){
    var link = $("a#coupon_link");
    link.data('href', link.attr("href"));

    $("#txt_name").on('keyup', function() {
        link.attr("href", link.data('href') + '&discount_code='+ this.value); 
    });
});
```

So as to not append the `&discount_code=***` several times, you need to store the original href somewhere, like in a data attribute.

Answer (score 0):

i think you need this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function(){
   $("#txt_name").keypress(function() {
     var value = $("#txt_name").val();
      $("a#coupon_link").attr("href",href+'&discount_code='+value.toString);
    });

});
</script>
```

look at `href`  don't know where you have that var, if it is needed ok else remove that

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
jQuery(function(){
    $("#txt_name").keypress(function() {
        var value = $("#txt_name").val();
        $("a#coupon_link").attr("href", '&discount_code=' + String(value));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This isnt working because the href isnt being changed as the function is called before a keypress event is triggered. Look into replacing keypress with blur and update the href when blur() is called

Answer (score 0):

this one worked for me getting value from input field and append it to the existing link using jquery.

```
$('#qty').on('keyup', function() {
           var theQty = 0;
           theQty = $("#qty").val();
           var oldHref=$("a#buybtn").attr("href");
            $("a#buybtn").attr("href",oldHref+ '&qty=' + String(theQty));



});
```